# JdbcOAuth2ProviderTokenServices

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

i am developing sparklr application i changed xml to

```
<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcOAuth2ProviderTokenServices">
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />

    </bean>
```

i take an error at client side 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'authantication.oauth_access_token' doesn't exist
        at javaapplication17.RestClient.httpPost(RestClient.java:74)
        at javaapplication17.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Java Result: 1

but ı have this column on db,instead of using org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcOAuth2ProviderTokenServices"

i need to develop my own class,but i cant developed it gives error is there any example
please help me!!

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception tells you the table `oauth_access_token` doesn't exist

Making this work with hibernate is harder (I've been working on it for a couple of days, perhaps I'll blog about it sometime soon). If you are unsure how to proceed, stick to the JDBC version and just make sure the table exists

Comment: thank you,but i need it really,but it is exist oauth_access_token

Comment: this is my db;  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oauth_refresh_token`;
CREATE TABLE `oauth_refresh_token` (
  `token_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `token` blob,
  `authentication` blob,
  `oauth_access_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`token_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: is there any schema that adresses this db really problematic

Comment: you have a _column_, but you need a _table_ with that name